# C# program deployment issues

Tags: c#

I want to deploy my C# program, but I'm having issues with running it on another computer.

I copied the entire folder from `bin/debug` to another computer and tried running the program. I receive the following error message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.5.24.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I thought it might be the issue of the computer not having .NET Framework 4.5.2 and tried downloading the installer from Microsoft but the installer states .NET

> Framework 4.5.2 or a later update is already installed on this computer.

Comment: forgot to copy "System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow" ? https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow

Answer (score 1):

This assembly it's not distributed with .Net Framework 4.5 you'll need to add to you project by NuGet, search online in NuGet package manager for Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow.

Comment: hi thanks for the help that seems to fix the error but i had another error now. `Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.`  

not too sure what that imported project means though..

Comment: from my project.csprof file, there is this ` <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` does that mean the host PC that im running the tool on must have this file?

Answer (score 0):

I got an same problem and my problem was a missing project reference after an update of an dependent package.

I had to reinstall my nuget packages with the command Update-Package –reinstall in the Package Manager Console.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages

After that the project references was newly added.